# swf chart not displayed in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to display the Chart of swf type. It is displayed proeprly in firefox and ie but in chrome it is not displayed. In chrome the chart will be displayed after a click on the chart div. Data for chart is loaded properly but will be displayed only on click.

my code is:

```
<?php
 $link = "/flash/Chart.swf?theXml=".urlencode(url_for('@chartCompare?series='.$seriesName.'&id='.$seriesId.'&source='.$sourceName,true));
?>

<div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
 <object style="z-index:-1" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="560" height="180" id="Chart" align="middle" >
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
  <PARAM NAME="WMODE" VALUE="transparent">
  <param name="movie" value="<?php  echo $link; ?>" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
  <embed src="<?php echo $link; ?>" wmode="transparent" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="560" height="180" name="Chart" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
 </object>
</div>
```

Anybody have any idea? ...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a website that we can check for ourselves or is this developed on your own comp?

Comment: yeah ... its being developed for the company ... thanks for ur reply ...

Answer (score 1):

Try removing param movie, worked for me.  It's kind of a hack but you just turn off that line if chrome (or can try !IE since firefox probably doesn't need it either).

Others have had luck with swfobject loading: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html